# Using the socket module in sandboxed Pypy

Tags: python, sockets, sandbox, pypy

I'm attempting to allow a subprocess sandboxed with Pypy to communicate, using a limited protocol, with the parent process.

After reviewing the source code of the `pypy/pypy/translator/sandbox/sandlib.py` included with Pypy, it appears that there is a `VirtualizedSocketProc` that allows `os.open` calls to open sockets. I've changed some functionality of the code (for example, allowing TCP connections on limited ports), but very little has been changed. However, I'm unable to actually import Pypy's `socket` module because it requires a non-existent `_socket` module, which seems to be located in the interpreter-level parts of the code.

Is what I'm trying to do feasible? If so, how do I import the socket module? If not, what else can I do?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you're trying to open the socket out of the 'protected' environment? (Not judging, I've done similar things numerous times -- and there's some approaches you may not have considered). It'd be easier to answer the question with more detail.

Comment: I'm trying to allow the sandboxed process to communicate with the parent process. Opening a socket seemed like a good idea; I have controls in place to restrict the port number, host, etc and sockets seemed like an easy way for the two processes to communicate.

Comment: Specifically, I want to offer restricted access to some functions available outside of the sandbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've investigated this further, and it appears that this is a fairly fundamental problem. The `socket` module, implemented at the library level (inside of the `lib` directories) is essentially an empty shell for the the `_socket` library, which is an interpreter-level module defined in the `pypy/module` directory. For those unfamiliar with PyPy, there are two types of modules that can be imported, roughly corresponding to the pure-Python and C libraries in CPython. Modules implemented at the library level can be included easily in the sandbox, and are in fact included in the "default" `pypy_interact` sandbox. However, modules written at the interpreter level are not available inside the sandbox.

It seems that my approach was fundmanetaly flawed, because of this critical distinction. Instead, there are a few other options that you can consider, should you run into the same problem:

1. Use `os.open` directly with a filename beginning with `tcp://`. This actually works very well and is my favoured approach.
2. Implement your own `socket` library. This is certainly not preferable, but I believe that it would be possible to create a relatively empty socket library that simply communicates with the sandbox controller as above wrapping the socket functionality. It might even be possible to *modify the default socket library* to achieve this (without including `_socket`, for example).